# Scraping multiple similar lines with python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Using a simple request I'm trying to get from this html page some information stored in "alt". The problem is that, within each instance, the information is separated in multiple lines that start with "img", and when I try to access it, I can only read the first instance of "img" and not the rest, but I'm not sure how to do it. Here's the HTML text:

```
<div class="archetype-tile-description-wrapper">
    <div class="archetype-tile-description">
        <h2>
            <span class="deck-price-online">
                <a href="/archetype/standard-golgari-midrange-60634#online">Golgari Midrange</a>
            </span>
            <span class="deck-price-paper">
                <a href="/archetype/standard-golgari-midrange-60634#paper">Golgari Midrange</a>
            </span>
        </h2>
        <div class="manacost-container">
            <span class="manacost">
                <img alt="b" class="common-manaCost-manaSymbol sprite-mana_symbols_b" src="//assets1.mtggoldfish.com/assets/s-d69cbc552cfe8de4931deb191dd349a881ff4448ed3251571e0bacd0257519b1.gif" />
                <img alt="g" class="common-manaCost-manaSymbol sprite-mana_symbols_g" src="//assets1.mtggoldfish.com/assets/s-d69cbc552cfe8de4931deb191dd349a881ff4448ed3251571e0bacd0257519b1.gif" />
            </span>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li>Jadelight Ranger</li>
            <li>Merfolk Branchwalker</li>
            <li>Vraska's Contempt</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Having said that, what I'm looking to get from this is both "b" and "g" and store them in a single variable.

Comment: can you share the code that you've tied so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably grab those `<img>` elements with the class `"common-manaCost-manaSymbol"` like this:

```
imgs = soup.find_all("img",{"class":"common-manaCost-manaSymbol"})
```

and then you can iterate over each `<img>` and grab the `alt` property of it.

```
alts = []
for i in imgs:
    alts.append(i['alt'])
```

or with a list comprehension

```
alts = [i['alt'] for i in imgs]
```

Comment: Thanks, technically that works! One thing I didn't mention in my post is that there are also other instances of the class "archetype-tile-description-wrapper" and everything else that comes with it, so running this loop actually grabs "imgs" from every other one.

Comment: okay, update your question to be more clear. I can only work with what you give me

Comment: Using your suggestion I was able to do what I was trying by putting the variable "imgs" and the loop inside another one that specifies what "archetype-tile-description-wrapper" class I was in. I've just begun using this site so sorry for anything wrong and thanks again :)